# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout/BindableLayout height calculation BUG? - Text wrapping breaks layout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've encountered a problem in Xamarin.Forms while trying to display grouped lists of items in a BindableLayout.

Following scenario:
I've want to display groups of items with a title in a frame, and the items in another frame underneath. Like in the following screenshot:

[image: Signe line, layout OK]

This works fine for me until the point, an item is too long and needs a line break, then the whole layout breaks and the groups overlap:

[image: Multiline, layout broken]

I tried removing the ScrollView, removing the TitleFrame but none works; it seems that the height calculation of the frame containing the items does ignore the labels wrapped height during layouting of the outer StackLayout.

Is there some issue with my code, or is it a BUG in Xamarin?
[Please find my example code here at GitHub.](https://github.com/daniel-streetec/Xamarin_StackLayout_Height)

PS: The issue is on Android AND iOS.

EDIT://
Code of page as requested:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinTestProject.MainPage">
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="24">
    <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="0,0,0,75" >
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="0" Margin="0" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemContainers}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AbsoluteLayout Margin="0" >
                        <!-- TITLE -->
                        <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,40,40" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None" Margin="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Green" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                        <!-- ITEMS -->
                        <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,52,1,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" Background="Gray" BorderColor="Red">
                            <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
    <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.65,1,0.25,50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional" Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,0.25,50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional" Text="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,0.45,50"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional" >
        <Label Text="Multiline" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Switch HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" IsToggled="{Binding Multiline}" />
    </StackLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you post here the page code ?

Comment: @Little_Dev added in edit. But the code is also available in the repo...

Comment: I would say that your problem comes from your AbsoluteLayout. Have you tried to change it to StackLayout ?

Comment: @Little_Dev you are right! Using StayLayout the layout is correct. But am I wrong or is it still a bug with the AbsoluteLayout?

Comment: There are no bugs. ```AbsoluteLayout ``` is used for just that kind of behavior, which is great in some cases. 
Check out the docs: [AbsoluteLayout is able to position children so that they overlap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout)

Comment: Yes, but I was stacking AbsoluteLayouts inside a StackLayout and they overlapped. This Behavior should only be possible when placing them in a AbsoluteLayout, the StackLayout should place the components under each other not overlapping

Comment: There must be a parent/child rule or something that explains this. I'm sure if you search a little more you will find it. This is where my Xamarin skills end.

Comment: @Little_Dev nevermind, putting it in the StackLayout solved the problem! Thanks for you support